# Route codeigniter url to another url segment

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes, codeigniter-3

I'm unable to route the following URL to a specified URI segment in CodeIgniter.

I want to route this URL

```
http://192.168.10.225/bachan/view/wholesale_detail/test-property/155454
```

to:

```
http://192.168.10.225/bachan/wholesale_detail/test-property/155454
```

in **CodeIgniter 3x**.

I have implemented below code but it doesn't work as expected:

```
$route['wholesale_detail/(:any)']="wholesale_details/$1";
```

in `routes.php` file.

Comment: noone dared to answer..very sad

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$route['bachan/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(:num)'] = 'bachan/view/$1/$2/$3';
```

In a route, the array key contains the URI to be matched, while the array value contains the destination it should be re-routed to. In the above example, if the literal word “bachan/wholesale_detail/test-property/123” is found in the the URL, the “bachan” class and the “view” method are instead used.

Comment: could he? I'm sure he _**could**_ do a lot of things. Expand on your answer, provide what it is he _**could**_ do.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$route['bachan/wholesale_detail/test-property/(:any)'] = 'wholesale_details/$1';
```